# Mysql query for a particular result we want

Tags: mysql

we have a following table

```
--------------------------------------
| Column Name     | Type             |
|-----------------|------------------|
| id              | int(11)          |
| rank_value      | int(8)           |
| allocation      | varchar(71)      |
| provider        | varchar(199)     |
| course_id       | varchar(4)       |
| category_type   | varchar(8)       |
| academic_year   | int(11)          |
| selection_round | int(11)          |
--------------------------------------
```

Now, my requirement is to find all unique rows with unique `provider` value, but here is the condition, but we have following condition

- `rank_value` should be highest
- `allocation` should be unique
- `category_type` should be unique
- for each `selection_round`

Would really appreciate your help in this!

Query given my ChatGPT but that is not working, as total unique provider (distinct) for us are 1249 and result is 144 rows

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.allocation,
    t1.category_type,
    t1.selection_round,
    t1.rank_value,
    t1.provider
FROM mbbs2023_year t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        allocation,
        category_type,
        selection_round,
        MAX(rank_value) AS max_rank
    FROM mbbs2023_year
    GROUP BY allocation, category_type, selection_round
) t2 ON t1.allocation = t2.allocation
    AND t1.category_type = t2.category_type
    AND t1.selection_round = t2.selection_round
    AND t1.rank_value = t2.max_rank;
```

**EDIT**

1. Other solutions on Stack Overflow don't work, as this table is some what complex
2. Some solutions are storing multiple columns data in single column to ease the processing

Comment: CrapGPT gets it wrong - shock horror

Comment: @Stu that's why we need humans

Comment: Post (a subset of) sample data and expected output. Otherwise it looks like a generic top-1-per-group problem.